# NetSuite Letter Template Not Merging

Tags: netsuite

I have created a letter template in MS Word and added the merge fields.

[image]

I have uploaded this to the File Cabinet under Letter Templates and created a Letter Template record. I then go to a customer click on Letter and select this template to merge. The letter is downloaded and looks exactly the same as the template, no fields have been merged. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you save the file from Word, you must choose "Save As" and select the "Word 97-2003 Document (*.doc)" option for the tags to work.

Comment: Mate, you're a legends. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

NL tags are no longer supported, as far as I know.  You might to update your templates to use the freemarker syntax.